# Remove Regular expression sensitive characters

Tags: regex, special-characters

I know it sounds like one of the questions about how to use regex to remove some characters. But my question is how would you use PHP or even regular expressions to clean a user input string from characters that might be recognized as an operation for the regular expression function and mess with it.

I take some input from the user and the use some of it to match html. So special characters like +, &, #, etc. are undesirable.

Thanks

[Edit]
answer for PHP:
$my_var = preg_replace($my_var);

Comment: Please provide us some sample text - what is the input and what should be the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell us the language!!! And you need to explain more detailed, what you want to achieve, "&" and "#" are not regex special characters.

A lot of languages have a function to escape regex special characters from strings.

e.g.:

in .net: `Regex.Escape()` see [Regex.Escape Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx)

in Java: `Pattern.quote()` see [Class pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

in php: `preg_quote()` see [preg_quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

there are similar methods in other languages, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace("/[\+\&\#]/is" , "" , $str);
```

Comment: thanks your answer works but stema's answer suits my situation better